# Make grown extracted tar file small again

Tags: filesystems, tar, compression, gzip, sparse-files

I packed and compressed a folder to a .tar.gz archive.
After unpacking it was nearly twice as big.

```
du -sh /path/to/old/folder       = 263M
du -sh /path/to/extracted/folder = 420M
```

I searched a lot and found out that tar is actually causing this issue by adding metadata or doing other weird stuff with it.

I made a diff on 2 files inside the folder, as well as a md5sum. There is absolutely no diff and the checksum is the exact same value. Yet, one file is as twice as big as the original one.

```
root@server:~# du -sh /path/to/old/folder/subfolder/file.mcapm /path/to/extracted/folder/subfolder/file.mcapm
1.1M    /path/to/old/folder/subfolder/file.mcapm
2.4M    /path/to/extracted/folder/subfolder/file.mcapm
root@server:~# diff /path/to/old/folder/subfolder/file.mcapm /path/to/extracted/folder/subfolder/file.mcapm
root@server:~# 
root@server:~# md5sum /path/to/old/folder/subfolder/file.mcapm
root@server:~# f11787a7dd9dcaa510bb63eeaad3f2ad
root@server:~# md5sum /path/to/extracted/folder/subfolder/file.mcapm
root@server:~# f11787a7dd9dcaa510bb63eeaad3f2ad
```

I am not searching for different methods, but for a way to reduce the size of those files again to their original size.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Are you saying that is the only file in the archive?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[this answer is assuming GNU tar and GNU cp]

> There is absolutely no diff and the checksum is the exact same value. Yet, one file is as twice as big as the original one.
>
> ```
> 1.1M    /path/to/old/folder/subfolder/file.mcapm
> 2.4M    /path/to/extracted/folder/subfolder/file.mcapm
> ```

That `.mcapm` file is probably [sparse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_file). Use the `-S` (`--sparse`) `tar` option when creating the archive.

Example:

```
$ dd if=/dev/null seek=100 of=dummy
...
$ mkdir extracted

$ tar -zcf dummy.tgz dummy
$ tar -C extracted -zxf dummy.tgz
$ du -sh dummy extracted/dummy
0       dummy
52K     extracted/dummy

$ tar -S -zcf dummy.tgz dummy
$ tar -C extracted -zxf dummy.tgz
$ du -sh dummy extracted/dummy
0       dummy
0       extracted/dummy
```

You can also "re-sparse" a file afterwards with `cp --sparse=always`:

```
$ dd if=/dev/zero of=junk count=100
...
$ du -sh junk
52K     junk
$ cp --sparse=always junk junk.sparse && mv junk.sparse junk
$ du -sh junk
0       junk
```

Comment: MCAPM is a MineCraft Anvil PocketMap file, described as holding "chunks" (segments of a map). Seems eminently likely to be sparse. I worried about the identical checksum, until I remembered null bytes and holes read back the same.

Comment: @schily fwiw, `dd count=0` not reading any block is not only the behaviour of GNU dd, also that of {Open,Net,Free}BSD's `dd`, and is also allowed by the [standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/dd.html): "`count=n`: ... If `n` is zero, it is _unspecified_ whether no blocks or all blocks are copied.". That doesn't mean it's right to assume it, as I [did](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/484913/revisions). So thanks for the heads-up.

Comment: that worked perfectly - thank you! (:

Answer (score 9):

@mosvy points out that your files were probably sparse.  Re-doing the archive + extract with `tar --sparse` works, or you can **make existing files in the filesystem sparse again using

[`fallocate -d`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/fallocate.1.html)** (from util-linux) to punch holes in in-place.

```
for f in **/*some*pattern*;do
    fallocate --dig-holes "$f"
done
```

The [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/fallocate.1.html) describes this option as

> You  can think of this option as doing a `cp --sparse` and then renaming the destination file to the original, without the need for extra disk space.

---

Linux supports the [`fallocate(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fallocate.2.html) system call which allows cool stuff like this, including closing up or expanding page-sized holes in a file to shorten or grow a file, instead of just turning a range into a hole.  It depends on the underlying FS to support each of the various fallocate features separately, and of course sparse files / extents in general.

It also lets you preallocate unwritten extents (like hole but with space reserved on disk), e.g. before a torrent download to avoid fragmentation.  That's where the "allocate" in the name comes from.

Other kernels that util-linux can run under may support some or all of this functionality, IDK.  If it doesn't work, `cp --sparse` and rename should work; sparse files in general (seek instead of writing zeros) are well-established and widespread in Unix, dating back *much* much farther than preallocated extents, punching holes, or especially expanding or collapsing holes between existing data.

Comment: I don’t get how large “holes” can escape being compressed by gzip.

Comment: @WGroleau: I'm not sure if tar can encode holes using metadata, or if it just lets gzip handle a long run of zeros (which it can compress with very good ratio).  But anyway, I'm suggesting using this on the already-extracted (without `--sparse`) files, not on the tar before gzip or on the .tar.gz (which wouldn't have any 4k runs of zeros).

Comment: Oops, I missed that OP said _after_ unpacking.   Does tar preserve hard links, or do they become separate copies of the item?

Comment: @WGroleau: I think at least GNU tar can detect hardlinks when archiving (presumably by keeping a hash table of `fs:inode` of all files its already archived), and make links when extracting.  The man page documents a `--hard-dereference` to *not* do that, like `-h`, `--dereference` does for symlinks.

Comment: @PeterCordes GNU tar is using special [format extensions](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_chapter/tar_15.html#SEC190) to store sparse files. Unlike what you're suggesting, `--sparse` has no effect when extracting. You could run `fallocate -d` on the extracted files instead of `cp --sparse`, but `fallocate` only work on some filesystems. The fact that GNU tar is using a special format may create problem with older `tar` implementations (but `bsdtar`, the default `tar` on FreeBSD, and the [`libarchive`](https://www.libarchive.org/) it's based on seems to handle it just fine).

Comment: @WGroleau [hard links](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/tar.html#SEC142). And of course, some testing won't hurt ;-)

Comment: @mosvy: ah, so it only detects while archiving, not while extracting, to preserve existing sparseness, not necessarily make them maximally sparse?  Makes sense, updated my answer to say re-archive as well.